# Join an Array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm looking for a method of turning a NSMutableArray into a string. Is there anything on a par with this Ruby array method?

```
>> array1 = [1, 2, 3]
>> array1.join(',')
=> "1,2,3"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 281, accepted):

```
NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

[`componentsJoinedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:) will join the components in the array by the specified string and return a string representation of the array.

Answer (score 18):

The method you are looking for is `componentsJoinedByString`.

```
NSArray  *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];//returns a pointer to NSArray
NSString *b = [a componentsJoinedByString:@","];//returns a pointer to NSString
NSLog(@"%@", b); // Will output 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 5):

[`NSArray` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
NSArray *pathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"here",
    @"be", @"dragons", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",
    [pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```