# Pull all objects in NSMutableArray and spit it out into a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Hi i have a nsmutable array full of keywords and i wish to key each object and spit it out with a comma after each object example below. The NSMutable array is called KeywordArray

Array Structure

```
Keyword 1
Keyword 2
Keyword 3
Keyword 4 
Keyword 5
Keyword 6 
Keyword 7
```

I wish to convert that NSMutableArray into the following format within a NSString

```
Keyword 1, Keyword 2, Keyword 3, Keyword 4, Keyword 5, Keyword 6, Keyword 7
```

Thanks

Mason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `componentsJoinedByString:` method of NSArray to join the elements in the array using a separator. This will work with an NSMutableArray as well, because NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray.

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

See the [NSArray class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"keyword1", @"keyword2" @"keyword3", nil];
NSString *string = [testArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Same case, but with NSArray was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845622/join-an-array-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

NSArray *arr;
[arr componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

Comment: Doesn't matter, componentsJoinedByString: works for NSMutableArray and NSArray. Returns a NSString.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's a mutable array, because NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. Therefore it has access to all methods that NSArray has.