# how can I Convert NSMUtableArray to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I convert `NSMutableArray` to `NSString`

```
bookArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[bookArray addObject:@"Book A"];
[bookArray addObject:@"Book B"];
```

Comment: `[bookArray description]`

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? "Book ABook B"? "Book A, Book B"? "Book A and then Book B"? "(Book A, Book B)"? "[Book A, Book B]"? "'Book A', 'Book B'"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Join an Array in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845622/join-an-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: You could try [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDECEE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Hot Licks comment you can use below code.

```
bookArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[bookArray addObject:@"Book A"];
[bookArray addObject:@"Book B"];
```

Then use Below code.

```
NSString *yourString=[bookArray description];
```

if you want to use `NSMutableString` and Some different separator then use Below Code.

```
NSMutableString* content = [NSMutableString string];

for (int aa=0; aa < [bookArray count]; aa++){
    [content appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<separator>",[bookArray objectAtIndex:aa]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple :

```
NSString *string=[bookArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "]; //your separator anything
```